# Black line showing on AdaptiveNavigationScaffold Flutter Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-windows

I am using the following AdaptiveNavigationScaffold implementation for a scaffold for a Windows flutter application...

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => AdaptiveNavigationScaffold(
        selectedIndex: StatefulShellRoute.of(context).currentIndex,
        drawerHeader: SizedBox(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
        ),
        drawerScrimColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        bottomNavigationOverflow: 10,
        body: ClipRect(child: child),
        onDestinationSelected: (int idx) => _goBranch(context, idx),
        destinations: branches.map((e) => e.adaptiveDestination).toList(),
      );
```

Everything is working well with go_router for handling navigation/state/all that good stuff. The issue I'm experiencing is with this black line showing up, and I can't seem to figure out where it is coming from. I can confirm this issue is not present when running the app with a web target.

[image: [Showcase of issue]]

I've tried to configure all the parameters of the AdaptiveNavigationScaffold but have not had any luck.

Git report: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-flutter-adaptive/issues/66